# IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext | Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, github-actions

I was trying to deploy a Spring Boot app to EC2 instance using terraform. In my github workflow I mentioned it as here.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Build Maven project
        run: mvn clean package
```

This one is failing on the Build Maven project step.

I am getting following error.

> [INFO]  [INFO] Results: [INFO]  Error:  Errors:  Error:
> TrackerieApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load
> ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4dd2ef54
> testClass = me.siyum.trackerie.TrackerieApplicationTests, locations =
> [], classes = [me.siyum.trackerie.TrackerieApplication],
> contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [],
> propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties =
> ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"],
> contextCustomizers =
> [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@25641d39,
> org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@18df8434,
> org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0,
> org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@3c77d488,
> org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f,
> org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0,
> org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@5d0bf09b,
> org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@33a0aaa9],
> resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader =
> org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent
> = null] [INFO]  Error:  Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0 [INFO]  [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  15.067 s [INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-07T04:19:40Z
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Error:  Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test
> (default-test) on project Trackerie:  Error:   Error:  Please refer to
> /home/runner/work/Trackerie-BE/Trackerie-BE/target/surefire-reports
> for the individual test results. Error:  Please refer to dump files
> (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and
> [date].dumpstream. Error:  -> [Help 1] Error:   Error:  To see the
> full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> Error:   Error:  For more information about the errors and possible
> solutions, please read the following articles: Error:  [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I do not write any test codes here, Just the code. Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>me.siyum</groupId>
    <artifactId>Trackerie</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Trackerie</name>
    <description>Trackerie</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You do have a test and it is failing. The test class: me.siyum.trackerie.TrackerieApplicationTests Just delete it if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed after removing following dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Seems like in the test scope it trying to test, but as there is no test cases it failing(Only my assumption, please experts correct this)